# Select from multiple rows based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table with rows of info on various units. This info is sourced from two locations, A and B. Source A contains info from every unit in the table, while source B contains more accurate info but only for some of the units.

How would I go about selecting one row for each unit, but prioritizing the selection of info from source B (when info is available) over source A, thus generating just one row for the unit with data from B? Right now if a unit is in both sources, it will come up as two different rows in my query. I've tried using a case when statement in the where clause and IF statements in the select statement.

I feel like there's a very simple solution to this but for some reason I'm struggling to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Table Structure:
UnitKey(PK)   UnitID   Hours   DataSource

Comment: Edit your question and add 1) table structure; 2) sample data; 3) what you've already tried

Comment: If you have a 1 to 1 relationship you should not be getting 2 rows or your code is not correct.  You need more details, like tables, data examples, desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select b.*
from b
union all
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where <matching conditions here>);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was previously importing both sources into one table through a procedure but I'll be putting the two sources in separate tables from now on. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Join the 2 tables, presumably `A LEFT JOIN B`. You can use a `CASE` statement in your `SELECT` to check if the information is available in table B, `ELSE` take from table `A`.

If you write a more detailed question I can write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    table_A.Unit,
    ISNULL(Table_B.Value1, table_A.Value1) AS [Value1],
    ISNULL(Table_B.Value2, table_A.Value2) AS [Value2],
    etc ..
FROM table_A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B ON Table_B.Unit = Table_A.Unit
```

How about that ?